# Mounted scouting with darkvision

Tags: pathfinder-1e, vision-and-light, mount

Are there rules for a character with darkvision riding a mount that does not have darkvision in absolute darkness? Obviously, DCs could be set for this, but is it even possible? Would the mount's mode of movement affect the possibility? Obviously this all at the discretion of the DM, but I was hoping for some advice from a printed source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your mount would be blinded

Barring any special abilities to negate this, your mount would be subject to the [blinded](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Conditions&Category=Combat) condition, specifically:

> **Blinded**: The creature cannot see. It takes a –2 penalty to Armor Class, loses its Dexterity bonus to AC (if any), and takes a –4 penalty on most Strength- and Dexterity-based skill checks and on opposed Perception skill checks. All checks and activities that rely on vision (such as reading and Perception checks based on sight) automatically fail. All opponents are considered to have total concealment (50% miss chance) against the blinded character. Blind creatures must make a DC 10 Acrobatics skill check to move faster than half speed. Creatures that fail this check fall prone. Characters who remain blinded for a long time grow accustomed to these drawbacks and can overcome some of them.

Finding a mount with high Acrobatics would be a good idea (though probably not as good as just finding a mount with darkvision).

Comment: ...or finding a way to grant your mount darkvision, for example by using a magic item.